# How to get a line of a text file as different variables in bash?

Tags: bash

Text file only contains X, Y and Z coordinates.

```
0.29399995009104407 0.5004167755444844 -11.279416799545288
```

I used `xyz=$( cat porecenter.dat )` to assign the content of text file to variable `xyz`. So `$xyz` gives me `0.29399995009104407 0.5004167755444844 -11.279416799545288`, but I need them separately. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for `cat`

```
while read -r x y z
do
    echo "x: $x, y: $y, z: $z"
done < porecenter.dat
```

If you only have a single line in *porecenter.dat*, there's no need for a while loop. The following will do:

```
read -r x y z < porecenter.dat
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way in bash is to use an array:

```
declare -a arrayxyz
arrayxyz=( $xyz )
printf "x %s  y %s  z %s\n" "${arrayxyz[0]}" "${arrayxyz[1]}" "${arrayxyz[2]}"
```

(**note the addition of braces...**)

That will rely on the default `IFS` (internal field separator) to split the words into separate array elements giving you `x`, `y` and `z`.

**To read an entire file into X, Y, Z arrays**

You can do this with a short script:

```
#!/bin/bash

fname="${1:-/dev/stdin}"

declare -a arrx  ## declare x, y, z arrays
declare -a arry
declare -a arrz

while read -r x y z; do     ## read file into x, y, z arrays
    arrx+=( $x )
    arry+=( $y )
    arrz+=( $z )
done <"$fname"

## output x, y, z values read
for ((i = 0; i < ${#arrx[@]}; i++)); do
    printf "array[%d] x: %-20s  y: %-20s  z: %-20s\n" \
        "$i" "${arrx[i]}" "${arry[i]}" "${arrz[i]}"
done
```

**Example Input**

```
$ cat dat/xyz.txt
0.29399995009104407 0.5004167755444844 -11.279416799545288
0.29399995009104407 0.5004167755444844 -11.279416799545288
0.29399995009104407 0.5004167755444844 -11.279416799545288
```

**Example Output**

```
$ bash readxyz.sh dat/xyz.txt
array[0] x: 0.29399995009104407   y: 0.5004167755444844    z: -11.279416799545288
array[1] x: 0.29399995009104407   y: 0.5004167755444844    z: -11.279416799545288
array[2] x: 0.29399995009104407   y: 0.5004167755444844    z: -11.279416799545288
```

Comment: It gives me x 0.29399995009104407[0]  y 0.29399995009104407[1]  z 0.29399995009104407[2] Is there a way of getting rid of [0] at the end?

Comment: sure, that was do to omitted `{...}` braces (my bad) `:)` Let me give you a complete example.